# How to create and link a bug to a specific iteration on a Test Result on Microsoft Test Manager (Microsoft Team Foundation Server TFS)

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I have a manual test result with various iterations. Some iterations passed the test but other s didn't. I need to create and link a bug to a specific test result iteration (the one that didn't pass the test) but when I choose to create and link a bug it always defaults to the first iteration. I can't see how to choose the specific iteration I want to link the bug to.

Before the click:

[image: Create and link a bug to a test result]

After the click:

[image: Bug creation dialog]

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380693.aspx they show how to link a bug to a test result. However, they don't specify on how to link a Bug to a particular iteration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this once the test run has finished. It's a usability bug that Microsoft needs to fix. At least that what a Testing Microsoft Partner say on the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsmantest/thread/8063510d-7a31-49bb-8b8d-64bafa5b822c). The only way to to this is from the Test Runner itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'd select it in Iteration dropdown under Classification above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but I'm afraid that doesn't work. The iteration dropdown refers to the iteration of the software development cycle of the implemented Agile Methodology that Microsoft proposes on it's default template, not to the iteration of the test case.